# Homeworld Cataclysm does not run on Windows 10

Tags: technical-issues, homeworld-cataclysm

I installed Homeworld Cataclysm on my Windows 10 machine, applied the 1.01 patch, and tried recommended command line settings I found in various threads online, such as `cataclysm.exe /heap 256000000 /enableSSE /triple /disableAVI /safeGL`. One recommended thing I wasn't able to do is set compatibility options to `NT`, which isn't available as an option in the compatibility settings, but I tried other compatibility settings (Windows 95, 98, XP SE2, XP SE3). I'm also running it in administrator mode.

Right now, what I see is that the game doesn't even run. Upon double clicking nothing happens except that Windows brings up a dialogue box asking if this program was installed correctly and if I want to do compatibility troubleshooting.

From reading other people's accounts, it sounds like most people are, at the very least, able to get it to launch. What am I missing?

Comment: When you say *other options*, what did you try?  You should be able to set the compatability mode of an application via troubleshooting it or by right clicking the `.exe` file and selecting properties -> compatibility.

Comment: @TimmyJim I meant that I tried the compatibility options that _were_ available. I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I found someone describing how they got Homeworld Cataclysm to work on windows 10.

Source: [Link to window 10 cataclysm setting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prJjGdW-W-A)

> Starting Options:
>   Okay i had to apply some things to the shortcut (if not present, make one) in >order to make it work:
>
> cataclysm.exe /heap 256000000 /enableSSE /triple /disableAVI /safeGL

I believe this is the setting you were looking for.

Comment: This was one of the setting combination I tried. Still doesn't launch. I also found other threads that recommend different combinations and still nothing.

Comment: Hmm it may be hardware specific. I don't know what else to do without more data.

Answer (score 1):

I got Cataclysm to work on Windows 10 a while ago, so I know it's possible.  From what I remember, the required compatibility mode was removed in Windows 10, so I had to make my own.  This is the process I used, to the best of my recollection, but it's been a while.

1. Download and install the [Microsoft Compatibility
   Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352).
2. Download [this compatibility database](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zh168v2utjqd6nf/Cataclysm.sdb?dl=0)
3. Run "Compatibility Administrator (32-bit)"
4. Open the database you downloaded in (2).  It should appear as "Homeworld Cataclysm" under "Custom Databases" in the tree on the left pane.
5. Right-click "Homeworld Cataclysm" and click install.

The database I'm using likely includes more compatibility fixes than actually required, but I just copied one of the pre-made compatibility modes and tweaked it a bit (don't ask me what I changed; I don't remember).
There's a [similar database](http://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/5-homeworld-hardware-acceleration-fix/) linked from [the Cataclysm page on PCGamingWiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Homeworld:_Cataclysm) that contains fixes for both Cataclysm and the original Homeworld.  I gave it a quick try and it seems to work as well, so try that one if the one I made fails for some reason.

That, along with the command line flags from your question should hopefully get everything working.  For completeness sake, these are the command line flags I have set:

```
/triple /enableSSE /enable3DNow /disableAVI /heap 1073741824 /window /noBorder
```

You may also have to fiddle with the registry settings under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Sierra On-Line\Cataclysm`  I seem to recall having to set `glToSelect` to `opengl32.dll`, and you can also set the screen resolution higher than the in-game settings allow (though widescreen resolutions cause some issues).